# Como simular tráfego/acesso concorrente arbitrariamente no Apache?

Tags: php, apache, desempenho

Estou usando o EasyPHP 14.1 Devserver, que vem com`Apache 2.4.7/MySQL 5.6.15.

Estou querendo simular alto tráfego e acesso concorrente para observar a performance e comportamento do meu site nessas condições, para fazer os devidos ajustes.

A pergunta é: como simulo essas condições? Há alguma ferramenta para simular esses casos ou abrir o mesmo *script* em várias abas já é eficiente?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você terá que usar um software apropriado. Até dá para fazer por conta própria mas dá trabalho e provavelmente você não fará corretamente.

Você precisa testar a carga normal e a superestimada até fazer o servidor não responder mais. O ideal é que a carga normal (ou um pouco acima do que pode ser considerado normal) fique rodando por bastante tempo (24 horas ou mais).

Só isto não basta, precisa tentar simular cenários realistas e que tentem criar situações inusitadas forçando a aplicação ou servidor ter problemas em situações pouco óbvias.

Já fizeram [uma lista](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php) de softwares para isto.

O próprio Apache vem um um utilitário para isto chamado [ab (ApacheBench)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html).

Se quiser algo mais sofisticado e pode usar Java a própria Apache encampou o projeto [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/).

Dizem que o [httpperf](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/) da HP trabalha com cargas mais intensas se for necessário.

Outro é o [DummyNet](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/).

Também já ouvi falar bem do [Seagull](http://gull.sourceforge.net/).